# OWL Parsing From EFO

Tags: java, owl

I have been trying endlessly to parse the Experimental Factor Ontology (EFO) file, but I am not able to parse it. The file I have opens fine in Protege, but I cannot seem to get it to load in Java. I have looked at a few sets of example code, and I am copying them seemingly exactly, but I do not understand why parsing fails. Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("entityExpansionLimit","100000000");
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
URI uri = URI.create("file:~/efo.owl");
IRI iri = IRI.create(uri);
OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri);
```

And here are the errors I get:

```
Could not load ontology: Problem parsing 
file:/~/efo.owl
Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or 
parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation.
The following parsers were tried:
```

Thank you, I know some similar posts have been made, but I have been unable to figure it out and am quite desperate! I can provide the stack trace if necessary, but it is quite long as there is a trace for each parser.

Comment: From the full stack trace, I believe the content of your local file is an HTML error message, not the actual ontology. Open it in a text editor and confirm the contents, please.

Comment: I have opened the ontology, it is fine, except there is a weird HTML format at the top. I think that may be causing the errors, I'm not sure why it downloaded like that.

Comment: The HTML will cause errors, that's guaranteed. Try deleting it.

Comment: I can't delete it and keep it as an OWL file. I would then have to re-save it as an rtf.

Comment: ? You most definitely can delete text from the file and leave the extension unchanged. It's just a text file.

Answer (score 0):

File URI need to be absolute for OWLAPI to parse them, but as you have a local file you can just create a `File` instance and pass that to IRI.create().

Alternatively pass the File instance to OWLOntologyManager::loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument()

Comment: I also tried this, I get the same error. I also tried making my file a ClassPathResource, and it did not work.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ontology directly without having it as a local file?

Comment: Is there any list of parsers being used? If not, looks like you're missing the parser definitions. Which Owlapi jars do you have on the classpath?

Comment: yes, here is the list:
The following parsers were tried:
1) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser@7741d8f0
2) org.semanticweb.owlapi.owlxml.parser.OWLXMLParser@7600ea6b
3) org.semanticweb.owlapi.functional.parser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser@42c70d23
4) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
5) org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.parser.ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser@574abbc4
6) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory@6f9c39ad

Comment: 7) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory@cd748dc3
8) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory@937ecd36
9) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory@27e81c
10) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory@dcacc47d
11) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory@9a5

Comment: 12) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory@69b9a3bc
13) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser@62fc071a
14) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory@27e82d
15) org.semanticweb.owlapi.oboformat.OBOFormatOWLAPIParser@60321c82
16) org.semanticweb.owlapi.dlsyntax.parser.DLSyntaxOWLParser@62f41349
17) org.semanticweb.owlapi.krss2.parser.KRSS2OWLParser@121331c4

Comment: 18) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory@3bf24493
19) org.coode.owlapi.obo12.parser.OWLOBO12Parser@256db4e7
20) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory@264e8d

Comment: Ok, so the parsers are found. There should also be a detailed report on errors encountered - we need to see that, or the actual ontology. Is it available online?

Comment: The detailed report is VERY long, is there a good way to share it here?

Comment: I have made a public googledoc with the error report. I hope you can view it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EE7NBJCOm0EKvgXQrTB7EJ14frBNe5FeMLaknrNo5FE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so I've managed to successfully load the ontology from the online IRI (http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo) but i am not sure why it doesn't work from my local file.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the local, downloaded file. Loading the ontology directly from the ontology IRI worked.