# Extract Specific Information From OWL Ontology

Tags: java, owl

This is a follow-up on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44163909/6893866) I asked yesterday. I have successfully loaded an OWL ontology, from which I want to extract specific properties from specific ontology entries, using the OWL-API in Java. Specifically, I am working with the EFO ontology. I would like to get the 'ICD9_definition_citation' and 'MSH_definition_citation' properties for a number of EFO entries/classes. An example class looks like this:

```
<!-- http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000676 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="&efo;EFO_0000676">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">psoriasis</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&efo;EFO_0000540"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&efo;EFO_1000636"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&efo;EFO_0000784"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&obo;UBERON_0000014"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <efo:definition rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">A common genetically determined, chronic, inflammatory skin disease characterized by rounded erythematous, dry, scaling patches. The lesions have a predilection for nails, scalp, genitalia, extensor surfaces, and the lumbosacral region. Accelerated epidermopoiesis is considered to be the fundamental pathologic feature in psoriasis.</efo:definition>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">A common genetically determined, chronic, inflammatory skin disease characterized by rounded erythematous, dry, scaling patches. The lesions have a predilection for nails, scalp, genitalia, extensor surfaces, and the lumbosacral region. Accelerated epidermopoiesis is considered to be the fundamental pathologic feature in psoriasis.[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:DOID_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">DOID:8893</efo:DOID_definition_citation>
    <efo:ICD9_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">ICD9:696</efo:ICD9_definition_citation>
    <efo:ICD9_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">ICD9:696.1</efo:ICD9_definition_citation>
    <efo:ICD9_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">ICD9:696.5</efo:ICD9_definition_citation>
    <efo:ICD9_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">ICD9:696.8</efo:ICD9_definition_citation>
    <obo:IAO_0000117 rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">James Malone</obo:IAO_0000117>
    <efo:MSH_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">MSH:D011565</efo:MSH_definition_citation>
    <efo:NCI_Thesaurus_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">NCIt:C3346</efo:NCI_Thesaurus_definition_citation>
    <efo:OMIM_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OMIM:177900</efo:OMIM_definition_citation>
    <efo:OMIM_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OMIM:602723</efo:OMIM_definition_citation>
    <efo:OMIM_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OMIM:605606</efo:OMIM_definition_citation>
    <efo:OMIM_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OMIM:612599</efo:OMIM_definition_citation>
    <efo:OMIM_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OMIM:614070</efo:OMIM_definition_citation>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OTHER PSORIASIS</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OTHER PSORIASIS[accessedResource: ICD9:696.1][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other and unspecified pityriasis</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other and unspecified pityriasis[accessedResource: ICD9:696.5][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders (disorder)</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders (disorder)[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200996000][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders excluding psoriatic arthropathy</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders excluding psoriatic arthropathy[accessedResource: ICD9:696.1][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Other psoriasis and similar disorders[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200996000][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PITYRIASIS NEC &amp; NOS</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PITYRIASIS NEC &amp; NOS[accessedResource: ICD9:696.5][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PSORIAS RELATED DIS NEC</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PSORIAS RELATED DIS NEC[accessedResource: ICD9:696.8][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PUSTULAR PSORIASIS OF PALMS SOLES</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PUSTULAR PSORIASIS OF PALMS SOLES[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PUSTULOSIS OF PALMS SOLES</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">PUSTULOSIS OF PALMS SOLES[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Palmoplantaris Pustulosis</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Palmoplantaris Pustulosis[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriases</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriases[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders (disorder)</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders (disorder)[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200955003][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders (navigational concept)</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders (navigational concept)[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200955003][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders NOS</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders NOS (disorder)</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders NOS (disorder)[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200997009][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders NOS[accessedResource: SNOMEDCT:200997009][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Psoriasis and similar disorders[accessedResource: ICD9:696][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustular Psoriasis of Palms and Soles</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustular Psoriasis of Palms and Soles[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustulosis Palmaris et Plantaris</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustulosis Palmaris et Plantaris[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:alternative_term rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustulosis of Palms and Soles</efo:alternative_term>
    <efo:bioportal_provenance rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Pustulosis of Palms and Soles[accessedResource: MSH:D011565][accessDate: 05-04-2011]</efo:bioportal_provenance>
    <efo:SNOMEDCT_definition_citation rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">SNOMEDCT:9014002</efo:SNOMEDCT_definition_citation>
    <obo:IAO_0000117 rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Tomasz Adamusiak</obo:IAO_0000117>
    <efo:gwas_trait rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">true</efo:gwas_trait>
</owl:Class>
```

I have tried a number of things, getting OWLNamedIndividuals, first getting all the classes, etc... Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Show what you've tried then we say whether there is a simpler way. It's more or less the same for properties like for classes. Note, in your example you need to get the annotation properties for a given class.

Comment: I'm trying multiple things:

Comment: 1) Get a single named individual:
OWLNamedIndividual owlNamedIndividual =
          efoOntologyService.getOwlNamedIndividual(ontology, "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000676");

Comment: 2) Get annotation properties for that individual: List<OWLAnnotationProperty> individualOwnAnnotationProperties = owlNamedIndividual.annotationPropertiesInSignature().collect(Collectors.toList());

OR

2) Getting object properties in signature: 
List<OWLObjectProperty> individualOwlProperties = owlNamedIndividual.objectPropertiesInSignature().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: However both are coming up empty, with no properties to show.

Comment: Ehm, you entities are classes at least the ones shown in the sample data. Shouldn't you get an OWL class with the URI then? And then get the annotation properties of that class.

Comment: I also tried it this way. Once I got this particular class: 
1) OWLClass example = owlClassList.get(0); (example = <http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_000076>)
2)  List<OWLObjectProperty> exampleOwlObjectProperties = example.objectPropertiesInSignature().collect(Collectors.toList());

OR

List<OWLAnnotationProperty> owlAnnotationProperty =
example.annotationPropertiesInSignature().collect(Collectors.toList());

OR

Set<OWLClass> exampleClasses = example.getClassesInSignature();

Comment: they are all coming up empty, except exampleClasses which returns the original class. do i want to get individuals from this class then?

Comment: No no no, do you know what the signature is? You are calling the wrong method. The signature of a class is just the class itself. You have to use the ontology object to get the annotation properties in OWL API 3.x. In OWL API 4.x you have to use the `EntitySearcher`, see http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/search/EntitySearcher.html#getAnnotations-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationSubject-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology-